How can I force the scrollbar on top of the background image?
In my Blazor site, my <main> contains both the .container for my @Body content and a background <img>. I recently went from allowing the entire <body> to scroll to having a sticky <nav> and scrolling content inside the .container in <main>. For some reason, this caused the #background-image to sit on top of the .container scrollbar when it's present, as seen here:
Background image on top of scrollbar
Here is the HTML for <main> in my MainLayout.razor file:
<main>

    <div class="container">
        @Body
    </div>

    <img id="background-image" alt="" src="assets/background.webp" />

</main>

Here is the relevant CSS:
main {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
    padding-top: 1rem;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 4rem;
}

#background-image {
    bottom: -8rem;
    filter: opacity(25%);
    overflow: hidden;
    pointer-events: none;
    position: fixed;
    right: -2rem;
    z-index: -1;
}

The background image was already set to z-index -1 when the change was made, and adjusting the z-index of the #background-image or the .container doesn't seem to do anything. Neither does adjusting the structure of the HTML.
How can I let the .content scrollbar sit on top?

OverlayScrollbars will do it.  (e.g. sandbox example)
